# Hook when admin partial refund in prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, payment-gateway, prestashop-1.6

I am developing a payment module for prestashop. I want that when admin partially refund for an order my plug-in function should call. I searched a lot and didn't find any hook that i should use to call my plug-in function.

I want hook for all cases.

1) When quantity of an item is refunded.
2) When partial amount of an item is refunded.
3) When partial amount of discount/shipping is refunded.

If hook is not available how i can override partial refund function in my module.

**Note : I don't want to change in core files as i want to maintain all from my module.**

Comment: Did you solve this problem?